# Capturing a live photo by camera in android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-image

I want to develop a payment app. This has the requirement to take live images by camera. By live image , I mean that the image should be captured from a person not from a image of person.

But if I take an image from image of a person that is not live image . Hope I am able to let you understand .

Comment: que is not clear .brief describe your question

Comment: you mean to say that you want to validate between live image and capturing from image? if it is not live capture will not be done ?

Comment: Yes  KDeogharkar . You are right .

Comment: Use camera preview and capture the preview frame live instead of using a camera ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent. If this is supposed to be some kind security feature you won't be able to protect against rooted devices faking the preview frames however. Or the person could take a "live" capture of a photo.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use face recognition for a person .

[FaceDetector.Face](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.Face.html)

> A Face contains all the information identifying the location of a face
>   in a bitmap.

([Face Detection Concept](https://developers.google.com/vision/face-detection-concepts))

> Face detection is the process of automatically locating human faces in
>   visual media (digital images or video). A face that is detected is
>   reported at a position with an associated size and orientation. Once a
>   face is detected, it can be searched for landmarks such as the eyes
>   and nose.
>
> Here are some of the terms that we use in discussing face detection
>   and the various functionalities of the Mobile Vision API.
>
> Face recognition automatically determines if two faces are likely to
>   correspond to the same person. Note that at this time, the Google Face
>   API only provides functionality for face detection and not face
>   recognition. Face tracking extends face detection to video sequences.
>   Any face appearing in a video for any length of time can be tracked.
>   That is, faces that are detected in consecutive video frames can be
>   identified as being the same person. Note that this is not a form of
>   face recognition; this mechanism just makes inferences based on the
>   position and motion of the face(s) in a video sequence. A landmark is
>   a point of interest within a face. The left eye, right eye, and nose
>   base are all examples of landmarks. The Face API provides the ability
>   to find landmarks on a detected face. Classification is determining
>   whether a certain facial characteristic is present. For example, a
>   face can be classified with regards to whether its eyes are open or
>   closed. Another example is whether the face is smiling or not.

is available from API level 1 .

Implement face detection in your app . Hope using this library you are able to differentiate person from a image of a person.

Here is some [example](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/10/28/implementing-face-detection-in-android)

Comment: Face is detected if I capture image from an image .

Comment: you can give constraint like using recognise more than one EULER in face orientation . as image is just image it has only one angle at a time . you have to study this concept and use it as per your need.

Comment: How can I recognize more than one EULER in face orientation in image in java ?